# send email with active job and sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have an active job that sends an email

```
class UpdateEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base

  queue_as :default

  def perform()
    NotificationsMailer.create_client("mymail@gmail.com").deliver
  end
end
```

Then on my code I call the perform later method

```
UpdateEmailJob.perform_later
```

I am getting a message that the job has been Enqueued

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued UpdateEmailJob (Job ID: 1a57232b-f6a8-4dc6-b612-8aca1b1dba2c) to Sidekiq(default)
```

But the email is not been send, how can I debug that ? Is there a way to explore the queue ? is there a way to force the worker to run all the queue jobs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the sidekiq mailers queue running? If not, run this:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

You can interact and debug enqueued jobs via the [Sidekiq API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API). Run `rails c`, then:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

Sidekiq::Queue.new("mailers")
```

This provide all of the jobs currently enqueued in mailers. From there, look at the API docs for different ways to inspect them.

Comment: Note he is queuing as "default", not "mailers".  But your answer is solid.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!